# How to add http/2 header in htaccess to push a file

Tags: .htaccess, http, http-headers, http2

I'm trying preload a file pushing it by an HTML header based on HTTP/2 directive. But I receive an error 500 after make any modification in htaccess file.

Here is the piece of code that i'm using in htaccess:

```
# add custom header to single file
<Files index.html>
    Link: </themes/PRS060142/assets/css/570eb83859dc23dd0eec423a49e147fe.woff2>; rel=preload; as=font
</Files>
```

Somebody knows what is the correct way to send HTML heads by htaccess?

Answer (score 2):

This is the [syntax for Apache](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_headers.html#header) (I've shorted the full path for readability):

```
<Files index.html>
    Header add Link "</theme...fe.woff2>; rel=preload; as=font; crossorigin"
</Files>
```

Note you also need to add the `crossorigin` attribute for fonts - because of [various reasons](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Preloading_content#CORS-enabled_fetches) :-)

Comment: The syntax seem correct, the file is preloaded but the initiator not appear like "push" in the network tab, appears like "other"

Comment: Ah I missed the fact you were pushing a font. They need a special `crossorigin` attribute. Answer updated.